# Save text and image in dictionary from getting subviews

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I having scroolViewController having UIImageView and UITextView.so how we fatch the UItextView text and image of UIImage.it gives error...

```
for(UIView *subview2 in [scroolViewController subviews])
{            
    NSLog(@"-----%@",subview2); 
    if([subview2 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        [dictImages setValue:subview2.image forKey:@"positionY"];
    }
    if(subview2 isKindOfClass:[UITextView class])
    {
        [dicText setValue:subview3.text forKey:@"text"];
    }
}
```

Or when we writhe this

```
for(UIView *subview2 in [scroolViewController subviews])
{            
     NSLog(@"-----%@",subview2); 
}
```

then console gives:

```
-----<UITextView: 0xb8791d0; frame = (5 10; 285 340); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb860a30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

-----<UIImageView: 0xb0c9d10; frame = (134 118; 100 100); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb0c8600>>
```

so how we save text and image dictionary  from getting subviews...????

Comment: what error it gives can you put that error in your code ?

Comment: Already added in both dictionary just add this after your code to check it:  NSLog(@"%@ | %@", dictImages,dicText);

Comment: Property 'image' not found on object of type "UIView"--this type of error show .

Comment: are you familiar with the `Key-Value-Coding`? one key **must have** only one object, no more... and you can add only objects, and you should know the output console is not a graphical interface, so on this console you'll never see any picture. :) and maybe the `subView3` just a misspell in the line `[dicText setValue:subview3.text forKey:@"text"];`

Comment: yes i familier with it.and also i correct my misspell. but still getting that error...i think for getting subviews  we put for(UIView *subview2 in [scroolViewController subviews]) so subview2 is UIview so it not having any property of UIimageview or UItextView.. when  i put for(UIimageview *subview2 in [scroolViewController subviews]) then it correct for UIImageView but what about the UItextView....I dont know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the compiler error, do:

```
[dictImages setValue:((UIImageView*)subview2).image forKey:@"positionY"];
```

Since you've already checked that it's the right class, casting it is fine.

Is `dictImages` an `NSMutableDictionary`?